# VSCode. Debug app written using CA Agile Central App SDK 2.1

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

I have an app written in javascript using CA Agile Central App SDK 2.1.

I am using VSCode as IDE. I was able to debug app in google chrome using developer tools but would like to debug in VSCode by attaching it to running process (rab run).

Below is my launch.json code for debug but step over, step into, step out arrows are disabled.

```
"configurations": [
    {
        "type": "node",
        "request": "attach",
        "name": "Attach by Process ID",
        "processId": "${command:PickProcess}"
    }
```

Comment: It may not fix your problem, but trailing comma on the last line is not valid in JSON.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? debugging browser running code on vs-code instead of chrome dev tools?

Comment: yes @r1verside that is the intent.

Comment: Have you tried https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2016/02/23/introducing-chrome-debugger-for-vs-code?

Comment: There's not, well you should change of job if you're in a place that makes you having to request a simple program extension installation. That could be an alternative

Answer (score 0):

You need to install an extension named `Debugger for Chrome` and use a specific configuration like

```
{
        "name": "Launch localhost",
        "type": "chrome",
        "request": "launch",
        "url": "http://localhost/mypage.html",
        "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/wwwroot"
}
```

You can get more info [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2016/02/23/introducing-chrome-debugger-for-vs-code) and [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-chrome-debug)